# How to export JavaFX Projects in JDKj11

Tags: java, javafx, export

When I use `JDK 11` to make `javafx` projects, my code works well and run perfectly but when I try to export this project, happen this error:

(I'M USING IntellIJ IDEA)

```
Error:Java FX Packager: 
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\rapph\.IdeaIC2018.2\system\compile-server\calculator_51b9fd91\_temp_\build.xml:3: Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:fileset
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Are you trying to use the JavaPackager from an IntelliJ ant task? Can you specify how you get there? Anyway, the packager has been removed from JDK 11, so that won't work.

Comment: Take a look at the new jlink tool of the JDK. With it you can build even smaller packages with an embedded  runtime on condition that you migrate your whole project to jigsaw modules.